# Como remplazar al máximo valor permitido en un input con Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una duda.

**`¿Se puede remplazar el valor escrito en un input por el máximo valor asignado?`**

Es decir, si el usuario ingresa un numero mayor al permitido esta que se remplace por `x` numero o mande un mensaje diciendo que el numero no está permitido.

Puse esto, pero en el input aún me deja ingresar más valores.

```
<input type='number' value='1' min='1' max='5'/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Sí** , es posible escuchando el evento [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/keyup) del `input` , luego capturamos el valor del atributo `max` y el `value` y realizamos la comparación , si lo que se ingreso es mayor , entonces se asigna el nuevo valor al `input` 
 que se obtuvo anteriormente

```js
$(function() {
 $(document).on('keyup', '#numero', function(event) {
     let max= parseInt(this.max);
        let valor = parseInt(this.value);
     if(valor>max){
      alert("El Valor no está Permitido")
      this.value = max;
     }

 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='number' value='1' min='1' max='5' id="numero"/>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hice un else para remplazar con el valor mínimo si el valor es menor a 1 que me remplace por 1 pero no funciona? por que se deberá? :o

Comment: Esto: http://prntscr.com/eu4191 pero solo me remplaza por el max.

Comment: @JhosselinGiménez la variable `min` toma `max` también, cambiar por `min`

Comment: Ah, cierto. Error mio. Gracias!

Comment: permite ingresar símbolo de negativo y si se puede ingresar valores decimales usar parseFloat en esta linea `let valor = parseFloat(this.value);`

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo 2 rutinas que hablan por si solas,

podrás usar la que mas se adecue a tus necesidades, Saludos.. ;))

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".noPermitir").on("keydown", function() {
  if(event.key.length<2) {
   var n=parseInt(this.value+event.key);
   if (isNaN(event.key) || n<this.min || n>this.max)
    return false;
  };
 });

 $(".reEmplazar").on("keydown", function() {
  if(event.key.length<2) {
   var n=parseInt(this.value+event.key);
   if (isNaN(event.key)) {
    return false;
   } else if (n<this.min) {
    this.value=this.min;
    return false;
   } else if (n>this.max) {
    this.value=this.max;
    return false;
   };
  };
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
No permitir valores menor a 1 o mayor a 100<br>
<input type="number" min="1" max="100" class="noPermitir"><br><br>
reEmplazar valores menor a 1 por 1 o mayor a 100 por 100<br>
<input type="number" min="1" max="100" class="reEmplazar">
```

Comment: Falla si escribes `-1` por ejemplo. Así que luego de obtener `var n` podrían agregar `if (isNaN(n)) {
    this.value='';
    return false;
}` para no permitir valores negativo. [para el caso de noPermitir] y para el otro caso de reEmplazar `if (n<this.min || isNaN(n)) {`

Comment: Gracias!!! @Cesar por tu observación, hé corregido con `isNaN(event.key)` porque con `isNaN(n)` también falla si colocas "1-".

Comment: Ah bueno perfecto, gracias por la observación, voy a corregir donde lo use.